# Wireless real-time control of RGB led strip using PWM and RF

Tags: rf, pwm, wireless, encoder, decoder

I would like to send three 8-bit PWM values (generated using an ESP32 and the ledc library) wirelessly in real-time.

From what I've come across, RF seems like a good option, however I would prefer **not using a microcontroller** (or anything programmable) on the receiving side (optimally, the signal should go directly from the decoder to transistors).

From the various examples online, it seems that perceivably "parallel" communication is possible using the HT12 pair, problem is they are 4-bit.

Is there anything at least close to the HT12 pair for 8 bits?

What would be the most cost effective (and noobie friendly) solution otherwise?

Comment: hm, you're doing a digital transmission of data. This really really suggest a digital receiver is what you want – something programmable. What is the *engineering reason* to not use a microcontroller?

Comment: *What would be the most cost effective (and noobie frinedly) solution otherwise?* Product recommendations are off-topic, but it will be a pair of microcontrollers modules with integrated RF capabilities, almost certainly.

Comment: ease of use and (presumably ?) cost. I do not posses the equipment necessary to flash MCUs, albeit it is indeed not that hard, i would prefer to avoid it. Moreover, as i pointed out above, i am already using an esp32 (on transmitter side), thus pairing it with a 433mhz transmitter/receiver seems like a good option (to my unexperienced eye at least).

Comment: ease of use and cost are both arguments *for* a microcontroller! These things come with cheap development boards (some < 20€); designing an analog transceiver system will take multple times that in prototypes. I'm really not sure why you'd want a 433 MHz system attached to an ESP32 – makes little sense to me; the ESP32 has all the hardware for RF comms built in. And if you can program an ESP32, then you already *have* a microcontroller programming equipment...